# C++ Magic 8 Ball with Vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to take a Magic 8 Ball program that was originally using arrays and change it to a program that uses vectors instead. The task that I was given was to take the code below and do a couple of things to it.

- use the push_back() function to initialize the vector
- modify the signature and prototype of the getAnswer() function
- modify the code in the body of the getAnswer() function
- remove any unneeded code, such as your constant for the number of
  answers

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <string>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <stdio.h>


    using namespace std;

    string getAnswer();


    const string exitString = "x";
    const int SIZEOF_ANSWERS = 8;
    string magicEightBallAnswers[SIZEOF_ANSWERS] = { "Yes", "No", "Maybe", "It's not certain", "The outlook is good",
                                                     "The outlook is poor", "Time will tell", "Most likely" };



    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        bool keepGoing = true;

        while (keepGoing)
        {
            string question;

            //prompt for and get the question
            cout << "What is your question?  (Enter 'x' to exit)" << endl;
            getline(cin, question);

            //this assumes that the user enters a lower case x
            if (question.compare(exitString) == 0)
                keepGoing = false;
            else
            {
                cout << getAnswer() << endl;
            }   
        }

        return 0;
    }


    string getAnswer()
    {
        int index = rand() % SIZEOF_ANSWERS;
        return magicEightBallAnswers[index];
    }
```

Comment: Describing a C++ problem as "having trouble making the change over to vectors and could use some help" is similar to describing a problem with your car, to a car mechanic, as "having trouble making the car go forward, and could use some help making its wheels turn". Can you be a little bit more precise, and explain what your ***specific*** question is?

Comment: You've not explained what problem you're having with the code you've posted, and you've not asked any sort of specific question. Please review [ask] and [mre], and then come back and [edit] your post to make it clear what you're asking.

Comment: Recommend reading more about how to use [`rand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) and [`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). The big no is you can't `push_back` (or do much of anything) outside of a function. You can declare and initialize variables. That's about it. But since you can initialize, if your compiler is reasonably up to date you can `vector<string> magicEightBallAnswers {"Yes", "No", "maybe", ...};`

Comment: @Aces Radix: Q: Did my example help?  One of the problems with C++ is that what you *don't* know very much *can* hurt you.  Which is why books like [Effective C++,Scott Meyers](https://www.amazon.com/Effective-Specific-Addison-Wesley-Professional-Computing-ebook-dp-B004V4420U) are such an important adjunct to learning the "basic syntax".

Answer (score 1):

This example might help:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

string getAnswer(vector<string> &  magicEightBallAnswers)
{
  int i = rand() % magicEightBallAnswers.size();
  return magicEightBallAnswers[i];
}

int main()
{
  vector<string> magicEightBallAnswers {
    "Yes",
    "No",
    "Maybe",
    "It's not certain",
    "The outlook is good",
    "The outlook is poor",
    "Time will tell",
    "Most likely"
  };

  // Initialize rand()
  srand(time(NULL));

  string question;
  while (true) {
    // Prompt for and get the question
    cout << "What is your question?  (Enter 'x' to exit)" << endl;
    getline(cin, question);
    if (question == "x")
      break;

    // Ask question
    cout << getAnswer(magicEightBallAnswers) << endl;
  }

  // Done
  cout << "Bye!  Let's play again soon!" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Specifically:

- Use C++ features to your advantage, to eliminate unnecessary code like "push_back() or initializing with "(8)".
- Never use a hard-coded constant like "SIZEOF_ANSWER" if there's a dynamic alternative like "vector.size()".
- Note the use of [pass by reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_reference.htm): in `string getAnswer(vector<string> & magicEightBallAnswers)`.
- You should call "srand()" with a seed before using "rand()".
- Etc.

Comment: `getAnswer` function takes a parameter which is unused.

Comment: Both the variable and function parameter `magicEightBallAnswers` should be `const` because they aren’t modified.